# ReCaptcha v3 works locally, but not on remote server (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, recaptcha

I am unable to get captcha to work on server. It works fine locally and I get it to return a score without issue.

JavaScript after button is clicked.

```
(function () {
$('#btnLogin').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/captcha/lasttry.aspx/CaptchaVerify",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var _response = JSON.parse(response.d);
            if (_response.score < 0.5) {
                $('#status').text("User is not human being! Score = " + _response.score);
                $('#status').removeClass('text-info').addClass('text-danger');
            }
            else {
                $('#status').text("User is human being . Score = " + _response.score);
                $('#status').removeClass('text-error').addClass('text-success');
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            $('#status').text("Error on Server!");
        }
    });
});
})();
```

CodeBehind:

```
  [WebMethod]
public static string CaptchaVerify()
{
    //It should only call once
    if (response.score == 0)
    {
        var responseString = RecaptchaVerify(Token);
        response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseToken>(responseString.Result);

    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
}
private static string apiAddress = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

private static async Task<string> RecaptchaVerify(string recaptchaToken)
{
    //try/catch omitted to try to see error with customErrors off 
    String url = $"{apiAddress}?secret={recaptchaSecret}&response={recaptchaToken}";
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    String responseString = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
    return responseString;
}
```

When I run it remotely I get the following error (1st image Google console, 2nd Wireshark):

[image]
[image]

Firewall is open to Google, I have added the site to captcha admin. Keys are correct. they have been checked and re-checked. I am not sure if I am missing something in the web.config, or if there is a setting in IIS manager that I am missing.

Comment: @samwu, If I open up Chrome on the production server and copy and paste in the link ([link](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=recaptchaSecret&response=recaptchaToken)), It will return the JSON object. I was able to get slightly more detailed information about the error by refactoring my code.  The error is:  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 142.250.191.196:443. Which means it is making it to Google and they are refusing it. My key is the same, I added both localhost and my site under the same "site" in the Google Admin Console.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else comes across this problem in the future, it was the WinHTTP proxy on the production server. The following code fixed my issue:

```
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/",true);
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
req.Proxy = proxyObject;
```

More info can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webproxy?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can't troubleshoot your problem just based on these error messages. You can try the following methods to get more detailed error messages:

1. Run the site directly on the server – depending on the configuration of your site/server, you may be able to see the real error if you load the site from a browser located on the same server.  You may need to turn off 'show friendly http errors.'
2. Temporarily add the following within the appropriate tags in your web.config file:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
     </system.webServer>
     <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="Off" />
       <compilation debug="true" />
     </system.web>
   </configuration>
   ```

After you have added those, load the page again to see if you can get a more detailed error.

3. Open up IIS Manager and try to open up some of the different features by clicking on the icon.  If there is an error in the web.config file and it can’t even parse it, sometimes you will get a helpful error in IIS Manager when you try to open a feature.
4. Look in Event Viewer.  Sometimes you can find the detailed error logged in there, particularly Application Event Viewer.
5. Setup Failed Request Tracing.  This will often give you details on the 500 error.  This is especially helpful if it is an intermittent 500 error.
6. Look through the web log files.   This is especially helpful for an intermittent 500 error.  You can often parse the log files to see if there is a trend with a specific page that is throwing a 500 error.